# Manipulating columns in awk

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I'd like to manipulate some coloumns to better represent some data as a graph.
So far I have all the data lined up like this, with the first line being the header, then the next two lines holding the x, then y data for that point. all the numbers in the file are seperated by a single tab. Like this:

```
200.023 468.865 567.976 647.711    ##this line is the 'header'
59.927  58.099  60.546  61.461     ##this line is x data
1576.77 2192.02 1630.22 1879.04    ##this line is y data
59.769  59.300  60.380  61.308     ##next x
1111.36 2674.2  1590.89 970.134    ##next y
##numbers continue down, and across the page
```

I'd like to take the y coordinate (column 1 line 3) and place it in the same line as the x (coloumn 2 line 2) separated by tabs, thus the line will now be twice as long. So that the header line doesnt fall out of place I figure I should add something easily identifiable like '"space" /t', but anything will do.
Output:

```
200.023 space   468.865 space   567.976 space   647.711 space
59.927  1576.77 58.099  2192.02 60.546  1630.22 61.461  1879.04
59.769  1111.36 59.300  2674.2  60.380  1590.89 61.308  970.134
```

Let me know if I should clarify anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk one-liner:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{gsub("\t","\tspace\t");print;next}!(NR%2){split($0,a,"\t")}NR%2{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s\t%s\t", a[i], $i;print ""} ' file 
200.03  space   468.865 space   567.976 space   647.711
59.927  1576.77 58.099  2192.02 60.546  1630.22 61.461  1879.04 
59.769  1111.36 59.300  2674.2  60.380  1590.89 61.308  970.134
```

Or in a more readable format:

```
$ awk '
    NR==1{
        gsub("\t","\tspace\t")
        print
        next
    }
    !(NR%2){
        split($0,a,"\t")
    }
    NR%2{
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
            printf "%s\t%s\t", a[i], $i
            print ""
    } ' file
```

Answer (score 3):

This calls for a script:

```
$ cat preprocess.awk 
BEGIN {                       # Before processing the file set OFS
    OFS="\t"                  # Set the Output Field Separator to a TAB
}
NR == 1 {                     # Process the header
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)       # Loop over every field in the header
        $i=$i OFS             # Add a second TAB to space headers correctly
    print $0                  # Print the header
    next                      # Get the next line in the file
}
NR % 2 {                      # For all the odd lines in the file (y lines)
    line = sep = ""           # Clear the line and separator variables
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {     # Loop over the y value
        line = line sep x[i] OFS $i  # Concatenate x and y values
        sep = OFS             # Set after to avoid leading TAB
    }
    print line                # Print the line
    next                      # Get the next line in the file
}
{                             # If here then we are looking at the even lines (x)
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)       # Loop over the x values
        x[i] = $i             # Store values in array x
}
```

This will separate the header with two tabs and collect all the `x` and `y` pairs over consecutive lines.

Usage:

Using the following input:

```
$ cat file
h1 h2 h3 h4
x1 x2 x3 x4
y1 y2 y3 y4
x5 x6 x7 x8
y5 y6 y7 y8
x9 x10 x11 x12
y9 y10 y11 y12
```

Produces:

```
$ awk -f preprocess.awk file 
h1      h2      h3      h4  
x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3  x4  y4
x5  y5  x6  y6  x7  y7  x8  y8
x9  y9  x10 y10 x11 y11 x12 y12
```

Answer (score 2):

If the header repeats throughout the file then this could work:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    m = NR % 5
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
        a[m, i] = $i
    }
}
m == 0 {
    printf("%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n", "" a[1, 1], "space", a[1, 2], "space", a[1, 3], "space", a[1, 4], "space")
    printf("%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n", a[2, 1], a[3, 1], a[2, 2], a[3, 2], a[2, 3], a[3, 3], a[2, 4], a[3, 4])
    printf("%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s %8s\n", a[4, 1], a[0, 1], a[4, 2], a[0, 2], a[4, 3], a[0, 3], a[4, 4], a[0, 4])
}
```

Would print this:

```
 200.023    space  468.865    space  567.976    space  647.711    space
  59.927  1576.77   58.099  2192.02   60.546  1630.22   61.461  1879.04
  59.769  1111.36   59.300   2674.2   60.380  1590.89   61.308  970.134
```

I actually placed `"space"` literally but you could just replace them with `""`.

Comment: @sudo_O It does but I actually thought that the header repeats itself as well.

Comment: @sudo_O Yes like I said I thought the header repeats itself as well. So it could only work like this: http://ideone.com/W28rhd. Anyway there's an accepted solution already so I just won't modify this for possible reference just in case.

Comment: You should make it explicit then.